An approach to avoid OOM issue for parallel tasks
I have written a program which basically reads a file, processes its records to extract some data using a third party library and then dispatches the data to a remote server.
To speed up the process, I am creating Callable tasks that takes extracted data, and performs data dispatch step, and finally using executor service to execute tasks. Third party library I am using seems to not work well in multi threaded environment, so I have not put the data extraction step in Callable task.
Pseudo-code is as:
Iterator<Record> records = .....
List<Records> batch = ....
Data extractedData = ....
List<MyTask> tasks = ....
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   Record record = iterator.next();
   batch.add(record);
   extractedData.add(extractDataUsing3rdPartyLibrary(record));
   if(batch.size == BATCH_SIZE) {
       MyTask task = new MyTask (extractedData,....); 
       tasks.add(task);
       extractedData.clear();
   }
}
executeTasks(execuytorService, tasks);
....
....
MyTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
       // dispatch extractedData
       // clear extractedData;
    }
}
 

But problem is that data extracted is memory heavy and as a result I am frequently facing out-of-memory issues.
I am thinking of an approach wherein I would check size of tasks intermittently, and if it exceeds certain threshold, I would process tasks created so far, followed by data clean up, and repeating the process.
I want to know if this is a good approach? And if yes, then what would be a good way of finding in-memory size of objects in java, as C++ like sizeof method is not available? Instrumentation API is something I came across, but it needs setting up agents.

What you really need is backpressure: you need to limit the number of concurrent tasks, and block extracting more data until there are threads available to process new records. This question has some discussion of how to do it, though I'm sure there are better ones.

For calculating the size, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52353/29470
